# Fast, efficient pandas Groupby sum / mean without aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

It is easy and fast to perform grouping and aggregation in `pandas`. However, performing simple groupby-apply functions that `pandas` already has built in C *without* aggregation, at least in the way I do it, is far slower because of a lambda function.

```
# Form data
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,3)),columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> df['g'] = np.random.randint(0,3,100)
>>> df.head()

          a         b         c  g
0  0.901610  0.643869  0.094082  1
1  0.536437  0.836622  0.763244  1
2  0.647989  0.150460  0.476552  0
3  0.206455  0.319881  0.690032  2
4  0.153557  0.765174  0.377879  1

# groupby and apply and aggregate
>>> df.groupby('g')['a'].sum()

g
0    17.177280
1    15.395264
2    17.668056
Name: a, dtype: float64

# groupby and apply without aggregation
>>> df.groupby('g')['a'].transform(lambda x: x.sum())

0     15.395264
1     15.395264
2     17.177280
3     17.668056
4     15.395264

95    15.395264
96    17.668056
97    15.395264
98    17.668056
99    17.177280
Name: a, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

Thus, I have the functionality desired with the lambda function, but the speed is bad.

```
>>> %timeit df.groupby('g')['a'].sum()

1.11 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.groupby('g')['a'].transform(lambda x:x.sum())

4.01 ms ± 699 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This becomes a problem in larger datasets. I assume there is a faster and more efficient to get this functionality.

Comment: You can use the vectorized method by removing the `lambda` with: `df.groupby('g')['a'].transform('sum')`. On my laptop this method is just as fast or even a bit faster than `groupby.sum`.

Comment: Thanks! That cuts time a bit more than in half: `1.85 ms ± 187 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: Does using np.sum run any faster than sum?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `sum` string is just a way to call the `np.sum` method, so it uses numpy under the hood. Will look at the source code later.

Comment: Perhaps this should be another question, but is there a similar solution for `df.groupby('g')['a'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x,[0.0,0.2,0.8,1.0],labels=False))`?

Comment: I dont think there's a vectorized way of doing groupby and qcut yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for

```
  df.groupby('g')['a'].transform('sum')
```

Indeed is faster than the version with apply:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,3)),columns=['a','b','c'])
df['g'] = np.random.randint(0,3,100)
def groupby():
    df.groupby('g')['a'].sum()

def transform_apply():
    df.groupby('g')['a'].transform(lambda x: x.sum())

def transform():
    df.groupby('g')['a'].transform('sum')

print('groupby',timeit.timeit(groupby,number=10))

print('lambda transform',timeit.timeit(transform_apply,number=10))

print('transform',timeit.timeit(transform,number=10))
```

the output:

```
groupby 0.010655807999999989
lambda transform 0.029328375000000073
transform 0.01493376600000007
```

Comment: You might have missed a zero in `transform`, for me this gives an order of magnitude faster timings.